Extract the specific <p> tag in which the user's cursor is currently positioned when the content of a Lightning Rich Text Editor changes
Lightning Rich Text Editor usually keeps value in p tags, when we press enter or hit a new line, it creates a new p tag. I want to identify and isolate the <p> tag where the cursor is positioned during an oninput event in a Lightning Rich Text Editor, for example:
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p> consectetur adipiscing elit. [Currently editing] </p>
<p> nec elementumn egestas semper. Etiam eget laoreet tristique, ex posuere ullamcorper</p>

Let's say the user is currently editing the second <p> tag. Then that only part (the second p tag) I want to store in a variable. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Would you like the user, to select the words you would like to store in a variable? or you just want the current tag the user is editing to be stored in a variable?

Want the current tag the user is editing to be stored in a variable
